# How can I create a transparent NSTableHeaderView for a black HUD window?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drawing, transparency

I would like to create a custom `NSTableHeaderView` which works well on a black HUD window. I created a subclass of `NSTableHeaderView` which created this result:

[image]

I do no drawing at all. This is the relevant code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    // no background drawing, just draw the text.
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}

- (BOOL)isOpaque
{
    return NO;
}
```

How can I get a transparent background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass `NSTableHeaderCell` instead. This code results in transparent header in my test:

```
- (void)drawWithFrame:(CGRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)view
{
    [self drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:view];
}
```